# terraform merge two maps with at least one common key

Tags: merge, terraform

I am looking to merge two maps with at least one common key. The merge function overwrite the value of common key from first map.

I have two maps with one common key .

```
Code 
locals {
  map1 = {
   "key1" = "value1",
   "key2" = "value2"
  }
  map2 = {
   "key1" = "value11"
  }
}
output MergedMaps {
  value = merge(local.map1, local.map2)
}


Output 

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

MergedMaps = {
  "key1" = "value11"
  "key2" = "value2"
}

Desired output

MergedMaps = {
“key1” = [“value1”, “value11”]
“key2” = “value2”
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please show your current TF code for that issue, and explain why it does not work. Any errors?

Comment: @Marcin thanks for feed back , I updated the post with code and the issue I am having with current output.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how to merge the maps?

Answer (score 1):

Its better to have same data structure in `MergedMaps`, rather then mixing lists and strings. So it would be

```
MergedMaps = {
“key1” = [“value1”, “value11”]
“key2” = [“value2”]
}
```

which can be obtained using

```
output MergedMaps {
  value = {for key in distinct(concat(keys(local.map1), keys(local.map2))):
              key => flatten([lookup(local.map1, key, []), 
                              lookup(local.map2, key, [])
                             ])
         }
}
```